# Codeigniter click url with id to view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to get a variable working on my next page.

In controller.php I have the following:

```
        $buttons .= '<a href="'.base_url('klant/profiel/'.$value['id']).'" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i></a>';
```

And the part that is about the profiel view in controller I have this:

```
public function profiel($id = null) 
{
    $data = $this->klant_model->getKlantData($id);

    echo json_encode($data);

    $this->render_template('klant/profiel', $this->data);
}
```

In my model I have this:

```
public function getKlantData($id = null)
{
    if($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM klant WHERE id = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM klant";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And in my view I have this:

```
 <?php echo $data['bedrijf']; ?>
```

I just want to echo out each colum of the row I have selected in the beginning.

This error I get:

```
Message: Undefined variable: value
```

Comment: Well as it states $value is not being defined. Why are you setting $data, then passing $this->data into the view? They aint the same thing. And what is in $data? What are the results when you echo json_encode($data)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your awnser. I tried $value and $data both same error. And uhm... json_encode($data) gives me exactly all the row data of that ID what I want but than filtered by each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you have implemented $this->render_template inside your controller.

You want to pass in a variable called $value so you need to set that inside your $data.

```
public function profiel($id = null) 
{
    $data['value'] = $this->klant_model->getKlantData($id);

    $this->render_template('klant/profiel', $data);
}
```

So this will make **$value** accessible inside your view. Now if your array has an id column, then **$value['id']** should now exist.

You should read the CodeIgniter documentation on how to pass values from a controller to a view.